# CW complex for Möbius strip and its homeomorfisams

Tags: algebraic-topology, cw-complexes, mobius-band

I have to find CW complex for Mobius Strip. I can find a CW complex for a Möbius strip with more cells (one 0-cells, two 1-cells and a single 2-cell). My cells are points $A=(0,0) \approx (1,1)$, part of circle $ABBA$ without point A second 1-cell is $\{(0,t)\approx(1,1-t) \mid 0<t<1\}$ and 2-cell is $\{(x,y) \mid x,y\notin \{0,1\}\}$.
(I am not sure this is good explanation, but I hope you understand).
I find homeomofisam for this cells.
$$f_2(z) = 
     \begin{cases}
    \frac{\lVert z \rVert_2}{\lVert z \rVert_\infty}z &\quad\text{if } z \ne  0 \\
      \text{} 0 &\quad\text{if } z =  0 \\ 
     \end{cases}$$ is attaching mapp for 2-cell
$$f_1(x)=\begin{cases}
(-x,1) &-1 <x \le 0\\
(x,0)& 0<x<1
\end{cases} 
$$
is attaching a map for ABBA. It is easy to see that these maps are continuous.
And $f(x)=\frac{x+1}{2}$ for second 1-cell.
Is this okey?

According to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2726357/cw-complex-for-m%c3%b6bius-strip), there is CW complex with one 0-cell,one 1-cell and one 2-cell. I think that o-cell is A, 1-cell is circle ABBA, and 2-cell is $Int(M)$, but I can't find homeomorfism for 2-cell. Can someone help?

edit:
[picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YeFqy.jpg)
on the second picture with red color is 1-cell
on the third is another 1-cell with purple color
and on forth picture with blue color is 2-cell

Answer (score 1):

> According to this question, there is CW complex with one 0-cell,one 1-cell and one 2-cell.

No such CW structure exists on the the Möbius strip. Moreover the linked question doesn't claim that, and the answer that claimed that was deleted.

It is well known that [the Euler characteristic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_characteristic) of the Möbius strip is zero. Because given a one $0$-cell, two $1$-cells, and one $2$-cell structure (which we already know is a correct CW structure) we have $1-2+1=0$.

While the Euler charateristic of any CW complex with one $0$-cell, one $1$-cell and one $2$-cell is $1-1+1=1$.

The Euler characteristic is a topological (even homotopy) invariant. All CW structures on a given space have to give the same value. And so the number of cells cannot be arbitrary, it has to satisfy certain rules.

> Is this okey?

No, it's not. For same reasons as earlier there is no "two 0-cells, two 1-cells and a single 2-cell" structure on the Möbius strip as well, because its Euler characteristic is $2-2+1=1$.

Your description is not really clear to me unfortunately.
I'm not exactly sure how you define those two $1$-cells. Still any non-zero Euler characteristic attempt has to fail.